# Is there a way or an extension to make it so your fonts in Visual Studio are not all white?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fonts, colors, visual-studio-extensions

I am new to Visual Studio and I have tried playing around with the font colors so not all my code is just 2 different colors. One color is for variable types and the rest of the code (for method names, variable names, etc.) is all white. In Eclipse there is varying colors for multiple things so it is easier to read and understand. Is there someway to have this in Visual Studio? Because trying to change it from white changes everything and you cannot choose specifics sadly. I've tried looking everywhere online, but cannot find help for this seemingly simple problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: well... i have more than 2 colors in vs... without doing anything... maybe a bug?

Comment: Reset your Fonts and Colors settings (Tools > Import and Export Settings... follow the wizard) to use the Visual C# settings. Visual Studio's defaults for C# syntax highlighting are moderately fruity-colored, and you can adjust that with a rather granular set of identifier types in Fonts and Colors in the Options dialog.

Comment: @madreflection I tried this and it says there was an error importing "CoffeeScript" settings if that has anything to do with it? And the font colors didn't change unfortunately

Comment: After you select "Visual C#", the next page allows you to select which settings to import. Deselect everything, and then select "Fonts and Colors" (under "All Settings" -> "General Settings"). That'll avoid the error in case that's blocking the whole import.

Comment: At the very least, just go into Fonts and Colors in the Options dialog, scroll down to the various "User Types..." entries, and have at it. If *that* doesn't work, something's horribly broken.

Comment: Assuming your VS is not broken, ReSharper [can do want you want](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/01/16/new-color-highlighting-features-resharper-2019-3/) for things like class names, methods, fields, enums, constants and even `// TODO`s

Answer (score 1):

**In my side**, I did not face the issue as you described. And VS IDE has the different colors for different types for the code by default.

I used the **Dark** color theme by **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Environment**-->**General**

[image]

The method name is yellow, variable name is gray.

And the option for setting the color of the code field is under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Environment**-->**Fonts and Colors**. And you can change the color for them as you want.

So I wonder whether your vs environment has some errors or you made some changes to that.

Or you could change them manually or just change to use the default, these are the several suggestions:

**1)** disable any third party vs installed extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**2)** reset all vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset all settings**-->**General**

**3)** close VS, enter your project and then delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder under the project folder.

[image]

**Or** you could create a new project to test whether the issue happens in a new one.

**4)** use `devenv /safemode` under **Developer Command prompt for VS2019** to start your VS. And then test whether your project has the issue.

**5)** do an initialization for your VS, close VS, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx`. Then, restatr VS.

**6)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or just update vs

**Besides**, [Resharper extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a powerful extension and has its own color classification for code types. And it is a paid extension and new users get 30 days of free.

But you have to make sure that your VS works without any errors. After all, VS has a normal color plan for the code. So that is your choice whether test Resharper.

Comment: Yes, thank you for this. I had some unknown error or bug and had to repair vs and everything seems to be working now!

Comment: [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/699534) since the answer helps you solve the issue. And it will help improve so community atmosphere.